# How to fill textbox with values dynamically in data table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am getting data back from the API which I was previously displaying  in a table cell. I have now added an input  box to the cell and I would like my values to now display in the text box.

My code below fills the values with a hard coded string "Time Remaining"

```
    columns: [
                    { 'data': 'Studentid' },
                    { 'Testid': 'Testid' },
                    { 'data': 'Name' },
                    { 'data': 'Surname' },
                    { 'data': 'ExamNo' },
                    { 'Studentid': 'Studentid' },
                    { 'data': 'TestName' },
                    { 'data': 'StartDate'},
                    { 'data': 'EndDate' },
                    { 'data': 'Description' },
                    {
                        'data': 'TimeRemaining',
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<input class="form-control" id="Markup" name="Markup" type="text"  value = ' +'TimeRemaining'+ '  >'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'data': null,
                        "defaultContent": '<button id="btnUpdateTime" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary glow" style="width:100px">Update Time</button>'
                    },
                    {
                        'data': null,
                        "defaultContent": '<button id="btnReset" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mb-2" style="width:100px">Reset</button>'
                    }
    
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function you're providing to `render`, the `data` argument will contain the value received from that field in the call to the API. As such you need to append that value:

```js
{
  data: 'TimeRemaining',
  render: function(data, type, row) {
    return '<input class="form-control" id="Markup" name="Markup" type="text" value="' + data + '" />'
  }
},
```

Note that this can be further simplified by using an arrow function and template literals:

```js
{
  data: 'TimeRemaining',
  render: (d, t, r) => `<input class="form-control" id="Markup" name="Markup" type="text" value="${data}" />`
},
```

Comment: When I used the first function which use render my inputbox now displays with <input type="/>   How can I get it to display the actual value